# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError in my android application

Tags: android, android-widget, out-of-memory

I have 18 images which create a flower when overlap eachother as a stack in my and app. All images are added to activity in XML file `android:src:'@drawable/blabla..'`... However when I run my app , it returns an error `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` .Please help me... I dont know how I can solve this problem.Thank you...

```
public class PapatyaFaliActivity extends Activity {
     private int[] startLeafID={R.id.imag,R.id.birstart,R.id.ikistart,R.id.ucstart,R.id.dortstart,R.id.besstart,R.id.altistart,R.id.yedistart,
        R.id.sekizstart,R.id.dokuzstart,R.id.onstart,R.id.onbirstart,R.id.onikistart,R.id.onucstart,R.id.ondortstart,R.id.onbesstart,R.id.onaltistart};
    private ImageView[] leafstart=new ImageView[17];
    private int[] leafResouseID={R.drawable.papatya_orta,R.drawable.leaf_1,R.drawable.leaf_2,R.drawable.leaf_3,R.drawable.leaf_4,R.drawable.leaf_5,R.drawable.leaf_6,
        R.drawable.leaf_7,R.drawable.leaf_8,R.drawable.leaf_9,R.drawable.leaf_10,R.drawable.leaf_11,R.drawable.leaf_12,R.drawable.leaf_13,
        R.drawable.leaf_14,R.drawable.leaf_15,R.drawable.leaf_16};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        for(int i=0;i<17;i++){
            leafstart[i]=(ImageView) findViewById(startLeafID[i]);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<17;i++){
            leafstart[i].setImageResource(leafResouseID[i]);
        }

        Thread timerThread=new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(2000);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally{
                    Intent menuIntent=new Intent(getBaseContext(),MenuFrame.class);
                    startActivity(menuIntent);
                }
            }

        };
        timerThread.start();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        for(int i=0;i<17;i++){
            leafstart[i].setImageResource((Integer) null);
        }
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: make them null on onPause() of activity

Comment: how can i make them null? Could you please be more clear?

Comment: So do u think this can help me?                                    @Override
 protected void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  for(int i=0;i<17;i++){
         leafstart[i].setImageResource((Integer) null);
        }
  finish();
 }

Comment: @Override
 protected void onPause() {
   for(int i=0;i<17;i++){ leafstart[i].setImageResource(null);
  super.onPause();
 }.This may help you

Comment: But this "leafstart[i].setImageResource((Integer) null)" returns NullPointerException...

Comment: reduce "i" to lets say 5 and see if it is running , it might be due to the size of images you are adding .

Comment: why you are initializing imageview inside for loop??what is there in your xml file??pls post

Comment: I could be wrong,but are you not creating new intents in a looping thread?

Comment: why you need this line leafstart[i].setImageResource((Integer) null)

Answer (score 1):

18 images it is not a big number. If you have OutOfMemoryError this means that your images are simply to big. Simplest and best approach is to adjust (reduce) resolution of those images to the size you really need.

If for some strange reason you need images with hi resolution then you should use miniatures in case if they are shown in small scale, so only one or two images at once are presented in full resolution.
To make alternations of drawable item depending of level of details use [ImageView.setImageLevel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageLevel%28int%29) (to change level of details) and define resource as [LevelListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LevelListDrawable.html).

Calling *finish* inside *onPause* is very bad idea!

Comment: 18 images is a huge size.. it really depends on how you store them, and release them correctly.

Comment: Ok. I didn't point out clearly that she uses images with to big resolution to her needs, I made corrections.

Answer (score 1):

Try reading your 18 Bitmaps from within your code. Place the Bitmaps in the res/drawable-hdpi folder. (there are different folders for different image qualities).
Set up the Bitmap fields in your code:

```
Bitmap alpha;
Bitmap foo;
```

Now initialize the Bitmaps in the onResume():

```
Options options = new Options();
alpha = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(game.getResources(), R.drawable.youBitmapName, options);
foo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(game.getResources(), R.drawable.youBitmapName2, options);
```

> Options will give you the ability to downsample. (I'm not sure how big your images are, but you might also want to use the scaling methods then).

In the onPause, clean up resources by calling:

```
alpha.recycle();
alpha = null;
foo.recycle();
foo = null;
```

As soon as the onResume() method is called, the bitmaps will reinitialize.

Comment: options is ot going to take anything? For example like that options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

Comment: @Emilla You do not want JustDecodeBounds set to true. This does not read in the image, it just works out its size. Look at `inSampleSize`

Comment: so can u tell me what options will take?

Comment: Try making the image sizes smaller:
set inPreferredConfig to a config that won't take up so much space, eg. RGB_565. If that doesn't do the job, then rescale.

Answer (score 0):

While creating the emulator, increase the 'VM application heap size' and 'ram' under hardware setting. This will hopefully solve your problem.

Comment: But my application is working in emulator well...I test it in real device in Android 2.1 ,2.33,4.0 and it works fine.. However when i trid to test it in android 4.1 it return OutOfMemoryError... I really can not figure out this... and since morning im struggling with that problem.

Comment: Ok. 
Have you tried changing settings on emulator..?
It should work. Give it a try.